How to equaly space collection instances on a curve
I want to have a small geonodes-setup where i put any type of curve (best in 2D as well as 3D), and have some control over which objects i distribute equally and semi random on it and that those extra objects are aligned to to curve direction. what do i miss?
I also looking for a way to have non destructive way control over how beveled/ chamfered the edges are


May I recommend to look at the warning sign displayed on the Curve to Mesh nodes header ? If it reads "Input geometry has unsupported type: Mesh", it means that the GeometryNodes modifier is not attached to a Curve. This happens if a Bevel is defined for the curve. This Bevel being applied before the GN modifier, the curve is now a mesh when entering the GN modifier.

The message says "Geometry cannot be retrieved from the modifier object."
It also happens, when I open a new file, add a simple Béziercurve(without any change of settings), and in the geometry Nodes Tab adding just the "Object Info" and a "curve circle" node into a "Curve to Mesh" node

I can not reproduce this error. Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Of course:
https://blend-exchange.com/b/kdZ2dR3X/

NB: This is not related to the initial question. You have this error message because the GN modifier is attached to the same curve object you are querying with the Object Info node. It is some kind of circular dependency. Blender is confused. One way to tell the story is that the Geometry of the Group Output node is the same object as the Geometry input through the Object Info node. As advised by Gordon Brinkman, it is a better practice to attach such a GN modifier to a mesh object if the output is a mesh.

This will be a bit longer and almost a step by step tutorial (file at the end), but I wanted to show the thoughts behind the creation of this nodetree. So first of all I assume you have a curve of some kind and make a tube of it as a cable or whatever. I assume further that equal and semi random distribution means you want to distribute them evenly along the curve with just slight variations of the exact positioning.

Now I instance my bracket object on the points and align the rotation to the tangent, but here is the first problem: The curve only has two points, the start and end point.

Nothing easier as that, I could resample the curve. The original Bézier curve has a resolution of 64 to be smooth, probably resampling with 32 is still smooth enough:

Well, it is a smooth curve, but way too many instances. Yes, there are different ways to reduce them with the Selection input of the Instance on Points node, however they will limit the flexibility of having an arbitrary number of points and later randomizing them. So just resample with a low Count value, I choose only 4 to clearly show the problems with that:

Unfortunately the curve is now only 3 straight segments. The first solution of course is to use the original curve for the tube and the resampled curve only for the instances:

As you see, the problem with this is that the instances are aligned with the tangents of the straight curve segments. This could be avoided if you use a Curve to Points node instead and take the Tangent output there, however for further curve-based customizations this cannot be used here.
Instead a Sample Curve node can be used to sample the tangent of the original curve at any given point along the Spline Parameter > Factor. This would be sufficient to instance an arbitrary number of instances evenly on an arbitrary curve:

But the goal here is to also randomize the instance positions a little bit. To do that, we need a Set Position node of course to move the points. And instead of the Factor we will use the Index of the points divided by the total Count of points minus 1 (because the indices go from 0 to count-1) to create our own "custom" factor where we want to sample positions and tangents. If we do not use the custom factor, the Tangent will not work correctly. I've increased the number of instances to 7 to have more to show how it works.

So now that the setup is prepared to modify the positions it is time to randomize them. This is simply done by getting a Random Value node set to Float and adding the result to the custom factor. Choose Min/Max values and a Seed value which you like, if you only want slight deviation from the even distribution the Min/Max values should be kept low.

One thing to note: the Factor input of the Sample Curve node clamps all input values to the 0 to 1 range. Which means, no instance will ever be positioned "before" the curve or "after" the curve, no matter how low or high the values get.
As you can see above though, this randomization can also result in having no instances exactly at the start or end of the curve, if the first point gets a positive random value added and the last point a negative random value. But let's assume you would want the first instance to always be at the start of the curve and the last instance always be at the end. Of course you could change the Seed until it fits your needs or even better: you use the Endpoint Selection node to only randomize all other than the endpoints. Set Start Size and End Size to 1 and use a Boolean Math node set to Not to invert the selection. The result will be 0 for endpoints and 1 for the other inner points, multiply it with the Random Value output to only add randomization for the inner points:

Or if you want to make sure that there are never instances on the endpoints, in this case you do not need the Endpoint Selection for the randomization, but instead for the Selection of the Instance on Points node:

Below another method to limit randomization, in the following setup I plug the Index into a Math node set to Modulo 2, so only points with an odd index get randomized. I'm sure you can come up with more ideas how to select which positions should be randomized, I will not show every possible solution I can think of and it always depends on what you actually want.

Addendum: As asked in the comments, if you want to switch between having endpoints or not, you can simply use a Switch node. You can either switch between two settings inside the nodetree or connect it to the Group Input node to switch in the Modifiers tab. Here I plug the nodes that remove the endpoints in the False socket of the Switch and simply enable the True checkbox - this will set all points to "true" so they are all part of the Selection that should be instanced. For the connection to the Group Input node I renamed the socket to "Endpoints?" so switching it on gives you endpoints, switching it off removes them.
Switching inside the nodetree:

Switching in the Modifiers tab:



This is amazing, thank you for explaining every step and what it does.
I could replicate it and even found a few tweaks to make it more individual.
At the end I just have to more questions:

I want to use a switch node for the last step, so I either have objects on the endpoints or not, how can I set that up?
And for me it just works just when I use the Group input, instead of the Object Info node, even if i have a new scene, with just a BézierCurve in it. Do I miss something

(working on 4.2.3)

@vp.gestaltung For the Switch node I've added something at the end of my answer. Sorry, I do not understand what you mean it works just when use the Group Input? You have to select the curve object in the Object Info node which you want to instance on - just like in my setup. And in this Object Info node you cannot use the geometry from the original object which holds the Geometry Nodes modifier. And if you use the modifier directly on a curve object, of course you have to use the Group Input then as this provides the original geometry.

@vp.gestaltung However it is a bad idea to add a Geometry Nodes modifier on a curve object, because although it works as long as you keep everything as modifier, you cannot simply apply it if you want to convert it into real geometry - because curve objects cannot have mesh geometry (which is what you get when you apply a GN modifier). Even without applying, on a mesh object you can add for example a Wireframe modifier to make a wireframe object of the GN result - but curve object cannot have a Wireframe modifier, and there are more modifiers that are not available for curves.

You could, for example, use Poisson Disk distribution:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

Imgur mirror

Or you could use an "Accumulate Field" node to position your points at increasing $x$ coordinate (or omitting that step and directly sample from accumulated length on the curve), and remove/don't spawn points that have the accumulated value exceeding curve length.
Yet another option is to resample the "Starting Curve" to desired length, and then set position to a position sampled on the same curve, but with a random value added to "Spline Parameter: Length".

Just an off-topic question: you always give additional links to your images on every answer and write, "SE image hosting has problems". Do you always have problems or every now and then and just post it every time to be on the safe side? I have actually never experienced any problems seeing images (only if someone messed up the linking), just occasionally I get an error when I want to upload an image - but then I try a second time, maybe a third time and then it works.

@GordonBrinkmann not always, they return every now and then. But it's not so easy to just refresh a page, once I have problems they persist for many days.

How annoying... I looked at the link to the problem description, this is really something that never occured to me.

You need to explain what you mean by semi random


One note to "Equal Spacing" setup: yes, this works in case you have only straight curves and resample with as many points as you want instances there. The question only shows straight curves without any bending, but if bends were desired even if it was just for round corners, you will get a problem if there should be only a few instances on this curve like shown in the question. Less points for resampling will result in a low-res curve, selecting instances via index and modulo limits the versatility of how many instances you want. And does not work well for (semi-)random distribution.

I think you misinterpreted my nodes. They do work.

I think you misinterpreted my comment. I did not say they do not work, but they only distribute evenly on all points of the curve - there is no way of randomizing the position of instances. Then the question asks for "any type of curve", your nodes will not work if the curve has a lot of turns for example or just in general when you only want a few instances so you resample with a low count and the result does not quite follow the curve - as you can see here, then the curve tangent will give an incorrectly aligned rotation: wavy curve with few instances
